# Magento form validation only works on the last checkbox in a group

Tags: javascript, validation, magento, magento-1.7

I am using the built-in Magento form validation to ensure the user makes a selection on a particular group of radio boxes.

The code below looks fine however

```
<div class="input-box">
  <li class="control">
   <input type="radio" class="radio organisation_type" value="1" id="billing:organisation_type_1" name="billing[organisation_type]"> <?php echo $this->__('School') ?></li>
  <li class="control">
   <input type="radio" class="radio organisation_type" value="2" id="billing:organisation_type_2" name="billing[organisation_type]"> <?php echo $this->__('Parent') ?></li>
  <li class="control">
   <input type="radio" class="radio validate-one-required organisation_type" value="3" id="billing:organisation_type_3" name="billing[organisation_type]"> <?php echo $this->__('Business') ?></li>
</div>
```

I am using the *validate-one* method on the class on the last radio box

For some reason the code above will only let me proceed if I select the last radio box?? Can anyone explain why if I check either the first or second box the validation is still failing?

Comment: Does [this post](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/out-of-the-box-form-validation-in-magento/) help??

Comment: thanks but still no joy :(

Comment: try adding: `class="radio validate-one-required organisation_type"` to all 3

Comment: try `validate-one-required-by-name`for all radio buttons

Comment: neither of them work.. this is really bizarre.. i hate Magento sometimes

Comment: When using the 'validate-one-required-by-name' method it will duplicate the error message 3 times? Although the validation does work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add `validate-one-required-by-name` to the last radio button.

```
<input type='radio' class="validate-one-required-by-name .. "
```

Take a look at `Payment Method` when placing an admin order
[image]

Comment: Thanks R.S - that does indeed work the only downside I seem to have is the "Please select one of the options" error message in red appears 3 times (once under each radio button) - any ideas why it would display it 3 times?

Comment: Did you try to do a test with admin order creation? Did it you have one or multiple "Please select.."

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the same ID in any case. Make your input `id` attributes always different.

Comment: thanks although i have now made them unique and the problem persists :(