# How to validate at least one checkbox in Magento?

Tags: forms, validation, magento, checkbox

I have a dynamic form with minimum one checkbox as an array.

```
<form action="url" method="post" id="whatever">
  <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="item_ids[]" value="101" />
  <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="item_ids[]" value="102" />
  <input class="checkbox validate-one-required" type="checkbox" name="item_ids[]" value="103" />
  <button type="submit">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //< ![CDATA[
    var customForm = new VarienForm('whatever');
    //]]>
</script>
```

I tried to use the hint from several forums to add the "validate-one-required" to the last checkbox in the group. But when I try to submit my form and I checked the first checkbox Magento told me that I have to select at least one option. Funny! I guess I did it.

Is there something else especially in the javascript area I had to add?

Comment: According to this answer it's `validate-one-required-by-name` -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23912566/magento-form-validation-only-works-on-the-last-checkbox-in-a-group

Comment: Could you find the solution?

Answer (score 4):

Try attach the class `validate-one-required-by-name` to all the input fields that you need to validate as long as they have the same name.

Comment: It works fine!
It is possible to use 'validate-one-required' too.
I would to share with you this interesting link: http://inchoo.net/magento/out-of-the-box-form-validation-in-magento/